# gradient and integral over paths

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ field over $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$. I want to bound $\|f(x)-f(0)\|$ by something depending on the gradient. It is clear that this is smaller than $\|x\|\sup_{y\in B(0,x)}\|\nabla f(y)\|$, but I am looking for a smarter way to do this.

For instance, one can look for the continuous path $\gamma$ between $0$ and $x$ that minimises $\int_\gamma \|\nabla f(x)\|$, but obtaining an explicit expression looks complicated.

So what I'm trying to do is do the average (hence the integral) over all paths that go between 0 and x, but it looks like something that requires some formalism. Has anyone seen something like this?

Comment: You certainly don't want to integrate $\|\nabla f(x)\|$. That's far too wasteful. Of course, what's true is that you get $\|x\|\inf_\gamma\max_{y\in\gamma}\|\nabla f(y)\|$ where you consider all paths $\gamma$ from $0$ to $x$.